# apply.daterangepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

[page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxsc.png)

`apply.daterangepicker` is not working. I want to call function when apply is clicked but it is not working.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="duration" name="daterange" >`
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
  });
});

$('#duration').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
  alert('apply clicked!');
});
```

Library : bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using?

Comment: Please post more code, so can get clear idea what exactly you are expecting

Comment: More code including image is updated in question please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
  alert('apply clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Priya your solution worked but my problem is something other....

Comment: But why doesn't it work with id selector?